# How to get the current attributes of an Eloquent model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I would like to get the keys of a model, not the columns in the database.

Here an example of what I would like to achieve:

```
>>> $model = Model::first();
=> [
     "foo" => 3,
     "bar" => 4
   ]
>>> $model->baz = 5;
>>> $model->keys() // What I would like to do...
=> ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

Unfortunately `get_object_vars` does not work here.

Comment: try `array_keys($model->toArray())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the attributes without its values

1. For model instance:

   `array_keys($model->getAttributes())`
2. For model's table name:

   `Schema::getColumnListing('tasks');`

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_keys($model->toArray())` to find the arrays. It will show you arrays of keys.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<?php

Hi nowox,

//in your Model create a method getKeysAtribute like
...
public function getKeysAttribute() {
    return array_keys($this->attributes);
}
...

 $model->keys() // ['key1', 'key2', ...];
```

Comment: The idea is to have this for any Model, not only some.

Comment: Ok, you can create create a base model and extends it

Answer (score 1):

Laravel Has a buit in out of the Method to do that

**this Method Wsa introduced in `laravel 5.4` So only app with 5.4 or with higher verision will only work**

```
//gets the first model from the table
$model  = Model::first();

//to get the original data With value
$originalAndData = $model->getOriginal();
//to get only the filed names
$originalKey = array_keys($model->getOriginal());
```

Comment: `array_keys` does not work: `>>> array_keys($model)
PHP Warning:  array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array,`